# Adding SVG items in QgsVectorLayer?

Tags: qgis, c++, svg, qt

I am trying to add an SVG icon with the help of QgsVectorLayer in the QgsMapCanvas but not able to do so.

Is there any mechanism to add an SVG icon to a layer?

Answer (score 1):

You need add svg icon in a feature for show miniature in a canvas?

Try this.

```
startSvgTag = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg><g>"""
endSvgTag = """ </g></svg>"""

data = requests.get(thumb, stream=True).content   
base64data = base64.b64encode(data).replace('\n','')
base64String = '<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,{0}" width="320" height="240"/>'.format(base64data)
```

The full code is https://github.com/All4Gis/instagram2qgis/blob/master/Insta2QgisDialog.py ,funtion **CreateMarker** and the result is:

[image]